# Pathlib how to deal with folders that start with a number

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pathlib

Using Python 3 pathlib on Windows, is there a way to deal with folders that start with a number, other than adding an extra slash?

For example:

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
op = pathlib.Path("D:\Documents\01")
fn = "test.txt"
fp = outpath / fn
with fp.open("w", encoding ="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Returns error: `[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\Documents\x01\\test.txt'`

I would have thought the `PureWindowsPath` would have taken care of this. If I manually escape out of it with `op = pathlib.Path("D:\Documents\\01")`, then it is fine. Do I always have to manually add a backslash to avoid the escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"\01"` is a byte whose value is 1, *not* "backslash, zero, one".

You can do, for example:

```
op = pathlib.Path("D:\Documents") / "01"
```

The extra slash in `"D:\Documents\\01"` is there to tell Python that you *don't* want it to interpret `\01` as an escape sequence.

From the comments chain:

> It's the Python interpreter that's doing the escaping: \01 will always
> be treated as an escape sequence (unless it's in a raw string literal
> like r"\01"). pathlib has nothing to do with escaping in this case

Comment: right, fixed that in the question. I expected path to not try to escape out of anything in quotes. I expected this because I understand Path is system agnostic and doesn't care if you are Mac/Linux "/" or Windows "\" (i.e., just easy copy/paste of a file path without having to change the slashes)... so I just assumed it would not try to escape out of anything in quotes

Comment: It's the Python interpreter that's doing the escaping: `\01` will always be treated as an escape sequence (unless it's in a raw string literal like `r"\01"`). `pathlib` has nothing to do with escaping in this case.